# How to force a browser tab (chrome) to use wireless and another to use Ethernet cable?

Tags: google-chrome, wireless, ethernet

I know that my question is a little awkward, but here's my situation:

I have two networks, one of them is accessible to me via wireless, and the other is accessible to me via an Ethernet cable.

If my laptop is connected to both networks, can I connect to website WW via the wireless network, and website EE via the Ethernet network, in two tabs in the same browser (Chrome) ?

Note: Assume both websites provide video streaming.

Note: Assume that website WW is blocked via Ethernet network, and website EE is blocked via wireless network.

My trials:

1. I tried to open website WW while laptop connected to wireless only, and then connect Ethernet cable, and open website EE. Result: Website WW closes connection via wireless, and tries to connect using Ethernet, hence stops streaming.
2. I tried to open website EE while laptop connected to Ethernet only, and then connect to wireless network, and open website WW. Result: Website EE keeps streaming, while WW never loads.

I'm using windows XP, latest google chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can reconfigure the access point, you can do this:

1) setup the Wifi access point to be a router (so that it has a different IP address on its Ethernet and on its Wifi interfaces

2) setup the IP address of the wifi card on your PC to be in the IP network of the router (Wifi side)

3) setup a static route on the PC so that WW is accessed by going through the router, and a default route (used for EE) going through the Ethernet.